# Ajax call is not performed inside a nested editor templates in MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to create a web app Admin tool for creating/editing quizzes, that can be fully adjustable (with ASP.NET Core MVC).

What I mean by fully adjustable:

1. Admin user can add/remove any number of questions per quiz.
2. Admin user can add/remove any numbers on answers per question.

The problem is that inside the `QuizViewModel` class, I have a collection of `Questions`, and each `Question` has a collection of `Answers`.

I've already created 2 buttons for adding and removing `Questions`, by using EditorTemplates and by performing a Ajax call to my controller method, which is adding/removing objects from `Questions` collection. Everything is working very well with all the bindings.

But there is the problem when I try to crate the same logic for add/remove `Answer` per each `Question`. I'm trying to perform the same thing as I did with `Questions` by assigning each answer's section div it's unique id, which is

```
string answersContainerId = $"answers-container-{Model.QuestionNumber}";
```

And do the same for Add/Remove Answer buttons.

Here is the simplified structure of my classes:

```
public class QuizViewModel
{
    public string QuizName { get; set; }
    public List<QuizQuestion> Questions { get; set; }

    public QuizViewModel()
    {
        this.Questions = new List<QuizQuestion>
        {
            new QuizQuestion() // First must-have question
            {
                QuestionNumber = 1
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
public class QuizQuestion
{   
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; } // Question duration (sec)
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public List<QuizAnswer> Answers { get; set; } // List of answers per 1 question

    public QuizQuestion()
    {
        Duration = 30; // default
        Answers = new List<QuizAnswer>() // When creating a new empty question, by default we create 3 answers for it
        {
            new QuizAnswer{ AnswerNumber = 1 },
            new QuizAnswer{ AnswerNumber = 2 },
            new QuizAnswer{ AnswerNumber = 3}
        };
    }
}
```

```
public class QuizAnswer
{
    public string AnswerName { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
    public int AnswerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is `Views>Quiz>CreateQuiz.cshtml` view (simplified):

```
@model QuizViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateQuiz", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-create-new-quiz" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h3>Quiz Name:</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuizName,"Quiz Name:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.QuizName, new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuizName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <h1>Quiz Questions:</h1>
        <div id="questions-container">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Questions)
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <button id="btn-add-new-question" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add new question</button>
        <button id="btn-remove-quiz-question" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove Question</button>
    
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>

}

@section Scripts 
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btn-add-new-question").on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                data: $('#form-create-new-quiz').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Quiz/AddQuizQuestion",
                success: function (partialView) {
                    console.log("partialView: " + partialView);
                    $('#questions-container').html(partialView);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btn-remove-quiz-question").on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                data: $('#form-create-new-quiz').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Quiz/RemoveQuizQuestion",
                success: function (partialView) {
                    console.log("partialView: " + partialView);
                    $('#questions-container').html(partialView);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I have an editor template `.cshtml` file for `Question` and `Answer` classes inside `EditorTemplates` folder:

1. `Views>Shared>EditorTemplates>QuizQuestion.cshtml` file:

```
@model QuizQuestion

@{
    string currentQuestionAddAnswerButtonId = $"btn-add-new-answer-to-question-{Model.QuestionNumber}";
    string currentQuestionRemoveAnswerButtonId = $"btn-remove-answer-from-question-{Model.QuestionNumber}";
    string answersContainerId = $"answers-container-{Model.QuestionNumber}";
}

<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(question => question.QuestionName,"Question Name:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(question => question.QuestionName, new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(question => question.QuestionName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div id="@{@answersContainerId}">
        @Html.EditorFor(question => question.Answers)
    </div>

    <button id="@{@currentQuestionAddAnswerButtonId}" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>
    <button id="@{@currentQuestionRemoveAnswerButtonId}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove Answer</button>

</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#@{@currentQuestionAddAnswerButtonId}").on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                data: $('#form-create-new-quiz').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Quiz/AddNewAnswerToQuestion",
                success: function (partialView) {
                    console.log("partialView: " + partialView);
                    $('#@{@answersContainerId}').html(partialView);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#@{@currentQuestionRemoveAnswerButtonId}").on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                data: $('#form-create-new-quiz').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Quiz/RemoveAnswerFromQuestion",
                success: function (partialView) {
                    console.log("partialView: " + partialView);
                    $('#@{@answersContainerId}').html(partialView);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

2. `Views>Shared>EditorTemplates>QuizAnswer.cshtml` file:

```
@model QuizAnswer

<div>
    <h2><strong>Answer @Html.DisplayFor(answer => answer.AnswerNumber)</strong></h2>
    @Html.HiddenFor(answer => answer.AnswerNumber)

    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(answer => answer.AnswerName,"Answer:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(answer => answer.AnswerName, new { @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(answer => answer.AnswerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-check">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(answer => answer.IsCorrect, new { @class = "form-check-input"})
            @Html.LabelFor(answer => answer.IsCorrect, "Is Correct", new { @class = "form-check-label"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Respectively, I do have 2 partial views for the editor templates:

1. `Views>Quiz>QuizQuestions.cshtml`:

```
@model QuizViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Questions)
```

2. `Views>Quiz>QuizAnswers.cshtml`:

```
@model QuizQuestion
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answers)
```

And finally, here is my `QuizController` class:

```
public class QuizController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult CreateQuiz()
    {
        return View(new QuizViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddQuizQuestion([Bind("Questions")] QuizViewModel quizViewModel)
    {
        QuizQuestion newQuizQuestion = new QuizQuestion
        {
            QuestionNumber = quizViewModel.Questions.Count + 1
        };

        quizViewModel.Questions.Add(newQuizQuestion);
        return PartialView("QuizQuestions", quizViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveQuizQuestion([Bind("Questions")] QuizViewModel quizViewModel)
    {
        if (quizViewModel.Questions.Count is not 1)
        {
            quizViewModel.Questions.RemoveAt(quizViewModel.Questions.Count - 1);
        }

        return PartialView("QuizQuestions", quizViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewAnswerToQuestion([Bind("Questions")] QuizViewModel quizViewModel)
    {
        // Define to which question to add answer
        var quizQuestion = quizViewModel.Questions.FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView("QuizAnswers", quizQuestion);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveAnswerFromQuestion([Bind("Questions")] QuizViewModel quizViewModel)
    {
        // Define from which question to remove answer
        var quizQuestion = quizViewModel.Questions.FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView("QuizAnswers", quizQuestion);
    }
}
```

So in the end, when I press the unique Add/Remove Answer buttons, my Controller methods `AddNewAnswerToQuestion()` and  `RemoveAnswerFromQuestion()` are not called.

However, the same logic works for Add/Remove Question.

So it looks like the problem is in Nested classes I think.

Really hope that somebody can help, I'm stuck with this.
If you need some more info to provide just let me know.

And this is my first ever question on Stack Overflow, so I do apologize if something is not well explained.

Comment: sorry I failed to reproduce your issue in my side with your code snippets, when mentioned that `my Controller methods AddNewAnswerToQuestion() and RemoveAnswerFromQuestion() are not called` so do you have any error messages in the browser console window?

Comment: @TinyWang Sorry, I made a few mistakes when I was simplifying the code for visibility. I forgot to include the CreateQuiz method inside the Quiz Controller and to uncomment the working code from Methods. Now, all code snippets are 100% working.
The problem is when I go to the Quiz/CreateQuiz page and press the Add/Remove QUESTION button, Ajax makes a call to the AddQuizQuestion() and RemoveQuizQuestion() methods, and the partial view for Questions is returned as expected, however when I press Add/Remove ANSWER button, AddNewAnswerToQuestion() and RemoveAnswerFromQuestion() are not called.

Comment: we only have js function written in the create.cshtml loaded into the application website, https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUW1Y.png    My idea is that we might have to redesign the view.. It's too complex for me.

Comment: Do you have any update on this question?

Comment: @TinyWang your suggested solution works! That was an important thing to know that inside partial views we don't need to use Scripts section . Thank you so much for your help and involvement!
Beside the main question, currently I'm thinking of how can we decide which exact question requested addition/removal of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see that we don't have the `<script>` for the `Views>Shared>EditorTemplates>QuizQuestion.cshtml`, which means we don't have onclick event handler for the `Add New Answer` button.

[image]

This is because in the partial view, we use `@section Scripts{ }` to surround the scripts. Let's remove `@section Scripts{ }` in `QuizQuestion.cshtml` and see the result.

[image]

I stopped the troubleshooting after hitting the controller method for the add answer button...